# How to transpose a single column into a single line of rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

I cannot seem to find a decent example of this, but let's say I have a result table that looks as follow...

```
result

100
200
400
```

And lets say the number of rows is always the same (in this case n=3), now I would like to transpose it and be able to name each column whatever I want...

```
result1   result2   result3

100       200       400
```

I looked into the `pivot` function but I can't seem to get it to work...

```
select * from total_results pivot(result for result in (result1, result2, result3))
```

However this give me errors. How can I accomplish what I want, I cannot seem to find a simple example that I can understand as `pivot` is proving hard to use.

Comment: Tag the DBMS that you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `row_number()` with  conditional aggregation :

```
select max(case when seq = 1 then result end) as result1,
       max(case when seq = 2 then result end) as result2,
       max(case when seq = 3 then result end) as result3
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (order by result) as seq
      from table t
     ) t;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select max(case when seqnum = 1 then result end) as result1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then result end) as result2,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then result end) as result3
from (select t.*, row_number() over (order by result) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t;
```

The key is to use `row_number()` to enumerate the values and then use that.  I prefer conditional aggregation, but the same holds for `pivot`.